# I am having a major issue with the GPIO in virtual env

Tags: python, virtualenv, gpio, gpiozero

When I run this code outside my virtual environment, it works. However, when I try to run it inside my virtual env I receive an error. I googled, and ChatGPT for hours. No success. Any thoughts?

Code ran:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep
from signal import signal, SIGTERM, SIGHUP, pause

def safe_exit(signum, frame):
    exit(1)

red = LED(26)

def flashingLights():
    while True:
        red.on()
```

Error received

```
/home/cisco/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py:300: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from lgpio: module 'lgpio' has no attribute 'SET_BIAS_DISABLE'
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cisco/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/pins/pi.py", line 411, in pin
    pin = self.pins[info]
          ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
KeyError: PinInfo(number=37, name='GPIO26', names=frozenset({'BOARD37', 'WPI25', 'GPIO26', '26', 26, 'J8:37', 'BCM26'}), pull='', row=19, col=1, interfaces=frozenset({'', 'sdio', 'gpio', 'dpi', 'spi', 'jtag'}))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cisco/Desktop/ledlight.py", line 8, in <module>
    red = LED(26)
          ^^^^^^^
  File "/home/cisco/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 108, in __call__
    self = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/cisco/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", line 192, in __init__
    super().__init__(pin, active_high=active_high,
  File "/home/cisco/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", line 74, in __init__
    super().__init__(pin, pin_factory=pin_factory)
  File "/home/cisco/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 75, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cisco/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 553, in __init__
    pin = self.pin_factory.pin(pin)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/cisco/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/pins/pi.py", line 413, in pin
    pin = self.pin_class(self, info)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/cisco/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gpiozero/pins/rpigpio.py", line 101, in __init__
    GPIO.setup(self._number, GPIO.IN, self.GPIO_PULL_UPS[self._pull])
RuntimeError: Cannot determine SOC peripheral base address
(myenv) cisco@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $
```

my requirement file:

```
arandr             0.1.11
asgiref            3.7.2
av                 11.0.0
Babel              2.14.0
beautifulsoup4     4.12.3
blinker            1.7.0
certifi            2024.2.2
cffi               1.16.0
chardet            5.2.0
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
click              8.1.7
colorama           0.4.6
colorzero          2.0
cryptography       42.0.5
cupshelpers        1.0
dbus-python        1.3.2
distro             1.9.0
Flask              3.0.2
gpiozero           2.0.1
html5lib           1.1
idna               3.6
importlib_metadata 7.0.2
itsdangerous       2.1.2
Jinja2             3.1.3
lgpio              0.0.0.2
libevdev           0.11
lxml               5.1.0
MarkupSafe         2.1.5
more-itertools     10.2.0
numpy              1.26.4
oauthlib           3.2.2
olefile            0.47
pexpect            4.9.0
pgzero             1.2.1
picamera2          0.3.17
pidng              4.0.9
piexif             1.1.3
pigpio             1.78
pillow             10.2.0
pip                24.0
ptyprocess         0.7.0
pycairo            1.20.1
pycparser          2.21
pycups             2.0.1
pygame             2.5.2
PyGObject          3.42.2
pyinotify          0.9.6
PyJWT              2.8.0
PyOpenGL           3.1.7
pyOpenSSL          24.0.0
PyQt5              5.15.9
PyQt5_sip          12.13.0
pyserial           3.5
pysmbc             1.0.23
python-apt         2.6.0
python-dotenv      1.0.1
python-prctl       1.8.1
pytz               2024.1
pyudev             0.24.1
PyYAML             6.0.1
reportlab          4.1.0
requests           2.31.0
requests-oauthlib  1.3.1
responses          0.25.0
RPi.GPIO           0.7.1
rpi-lcd            0.0.3
RTIMULib           7.2.1
sense-hat          2.6.0
setuptools         66.1.1
simplejpeg         1.7.2
simplejson         3.19.2
six                1.16.0
smbus              1.1.post2
smbus2             0.4.3
soupsieve          2.5
spidev             3.6
ssh-import-id      5.11
toml               0.10.2
twython            3.9.1
typing_extensions  4.10.0
urllib3            2.2.1
v4l2-python3       0.3.4
webencodings       0.5.1
Werkzeug           3.0.1
wheel              0.42.0
zipp               3.17.0
```

- I tried matching packages
- I tried googling
- I tried chatGPT
- I reboot

Comment: Sounds like different libraries in virtual environment vs outside of it. Check what packages you have installed in which version, and switch everything to the ones that work.

Answer (score 0):

**The code you provided did not allow me to repeat the error you received.**

Try to do this:

`red = LED('GPIO26')`

### But I'm confused by your requirement file, it's too colorful !?

I would do so:

1. deactivated venv
2. deleted the venv folder
3. reinstalled the dependencies required for this project
4. created a new requirements file

The hygiene of the virtual environment is very important...

***Good luck!***

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35762914)

Comment: Fixed it. Is that better?